# Blackberry Push Notifications (Local Notifications)

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, blackberry-push

Can you set up Notifications on the blackberry without a server?

I wish to use the equivalent of Push Notifications, but I don't really need a server to decide when to push as it's really just calendar pre-set dates.

Any help thoughts /comments most appreciated

Cheers

~David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is the calendar itself?  (device or backend server)  If it's all on the device then your app can simply sleep until the next calendar pre-set date occurs.

Comment: Well the list of dates/time are generated based off a quiz on the phone. Say at 7pm Sunday it would randomly notify the user to do xyz related to the quiz.

Comment: unless you already have a backend for some other purpose it sounds to me like using the BB push service is overkill.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know, it seemed strange that one could receive push notifications, while there was no way to setup the equivalent based on a Date/Time. Cheers

Comment: @DavidvanDugteren So do you have the code now? I'm confused how to do this, I'm not a blackberry user but I need local notifications after every 10 minutes It should check from the server for the next data. I don't know where to start.